# Deleting rows from child table without deleting from parent

Tags: postgresql, delete, inheritance

I have 2 tables, connected with **inheritance**.
I want to delete some rows from the child table. The deletion part works but it deletes rows from the parent as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION earthquakes_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO earthquakes VALUES (NEW.*);
    DELETE FROM ONLY earthquakes WHERE datetime < (now() - '2 days'::interval);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER earthquakes_trigger
        BEFORE INSERT ON earthquakes_ovr
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE earthquakes_trigger();
```

Parent table : `earthquakes_ovr`
Child table: `earthquakes`

I also tried to break up the trigger function, and have the deletion part as trigger function on the child, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see that is not the case, when  the tables are not linked in anyway

> ```
> CREATE tABLE earthquakes_ovr ("datetime" timestamp)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO earthquakes_ovr VALUES (NOW() - INTERVAL '6 DAYS')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO earthquakes_ovr VALUES (now() - INTERVAL'4 days')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE  earthquakes AS SELECT * FROM earthquakes_ovr
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION earthquakes_trigger()
>     RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
>     BEGIN
>         INSERT INTO earthquakes VALUES (NEW.*);
>         DELETE FROM ONLY earthquakes WHERE datetime < (now() - '2 days'::interval);
>         RETURN NEW;
>     END;
>     $$
>     LANGUAGE plpgsql;
>     
>     CREATE TRIGGER earthquakes_trigger
>             BEFORE INSERT ON earthquakes_ovr
>             FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE earthquakes_trigger();
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO earthquakes_ovr VALUES (now())
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM earthquakes_ovr
> ```
>
> ```
> | datetime                   |
> | :------------------------- |
> | 2021-04-18 00:11:15.191671 |
> | 2021-04-20 00:11:15.203608 |
> | 2021-04-24 00:11:15.267616 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM earthquakes
> ```
>
> ```
> | datetime                   |
> | :------------------------- |
> | 2021-04-24 00:11:15.267616 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=655b1b4c4d378be539d8b3a094ed57ed)*

Answer (score 0):

While targeting the **child** table directly (`earthquakes` in your case), rows form the parent table are not affected. You got that backwards, the `ONLY` keyword has no effect here (is just noise):

> ```
> DELETE FROM ONLY earthquakes ...
> ```

[The manual on `DELETE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html)

> If `ONLY` is specified before the table name, matching rows are deleted from the named table only. If `ONLY` is not specified, matching rows are also deleted from any tables inheriting from the named table.

`ONLY` can make sense targeting the **parent** table (`earthquakes_ovr` in your case).

Consider a [partitioned table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) instead of inheritance. Then you don't need to re-route inserts to the parent table manually. [The manual on `INSERT`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> If the specified table is a partitioned table, each row is routed to the appropriate partition and inserted into it.

Comment: Well , I initially had it as DELETE but it didn't work so I'm probably missing something that is obvious . Thank you for your help.